# Use dynamic tags in HTML Ebay listing

Tags: html, css, ebay-design-templates

I've created an Ebay listing HTML template, but currently everything is hardcoded.

Is it possible to grab the product I'm sellings name, description dynamically?

I'm sure they used to have tags like {{ name }}, {{ description }} etc.

But it doesn't seem to work now?

For e.g.

```
<div class="products-description">
    <span>{{ name }}</span>
    <p>
        {{ description }}
    </p>
        <div class="button-position">
        <button type="button" name="button" class="img-position">Buy it now</button>
        </div>
</div>
```

Doesn't work.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but you'll need to use the API.  You can write a script that uses the item ID to lookup the data on the item, and use js or php to work some magic and put the bits you want into the template.

This works a treat and I do this for all my clients, though come next year js won't be allowed at all on templates, so you might want to write something that inserts it dynamically at the time of listing...